# How to handle associating a User with a Model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app that uses Django (well the Django Rest Framework) and I'd like to use [Token Based Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication). I'm not 100% clear on how I'd associate a User with a my Model at runtime.

So, [I'll receive a POST request in my View](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ....
    serializer.save()
```

And then, [the flow will go to the post save receiver](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
if created:
    Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I suppose that in my Model, I'll need a reference to the User. But how do I get a new or existing User in the View?
I suppose this will be my Model:

```
class UserPostData:
    some_info = models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

But how do I handle associating the User with the Model I just saved in the view?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # get_or_create_user()? But there's no username. It's token based auth
    serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a request is authenticated then you can extract user object from the request.
For example, you can overwrite a method `create` of your serializer and take request from the context, like the following:

```
class UserPostDataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        new_model = UserPostData.objects.create(user=user,
                                                **validated_data)
        new_model.save()
        return new_model
    ...
```

Comment: Alright. Thanks. So I guess, that's what they're talking about here: `If successfully authenticated, TokenAuthentication provides the following credentials: request.user will be a Django User instance.` But what if the request is not successfully authenticated? Then the flow will go to `@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but I suppose they create auth token only when client provides correct authentication credentials, otherwise it simply does not make much sense.

Comment: This setup has no passwords. It's token based.